# Redeclaring variable using the same name is legal in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm a newbie in Lua and I just found out the following code is legal in Lua.

```
local abc = 123
local abc = 345
print(abc)
```

Is there any difference between the above and the following?

```
local abc = 123 
abc = 345
print(abc)
```

Comment: there should be no difference for your example. However if local is defined in a new block, it will hide the other one. https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html

Comment: @CoderPi Striking out the "if local is defined in a new block" will make your statements true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each execution of a local statement defines new local variables [check this](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.5)
both variables have a separate identity but using the same name will hide the first one

```
local abc =  123
local function abc1()
  print(abc)
end

local abc = 345
local function abc2()
  print(abc)
end

print(abc1()) -- 123
print(abc2()) -- 345
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference. The first code has two local variables whereas the second one has only one. This can be detected using the debug library for instance. Compare the output of `luac -l` on both scripts.

Comment: It can also be detected by creating a function that accesses/manipulates the first variable before creating the second.